# Google YouTube API not retrieving all videos

Tags: c#, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the v3 Google YouTubeAPI to get all videos from a channel, but of the 3 available, only one is returned.  Any idea what is going wrong?  Here is the code for the function:

```
public List<Video> GetVideos()
{
   var vids = new List<Video>();

   YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer());

   SearchResource.ListRequest listRequest = youtube.Search.List("id,snippet");

   listRequest.Key = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["youTubeKey"];
   listRequest.ChannelId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["youTubeChannel"];
   listRequest.MaxResults = 25;
   listRequest.Type = "video";
   SearchListResponse resp = listRequest.Execute();

   foreach (SearchResult result in resp.Items)
   {
      vids.Add(new Video(result.Id.VideoId, result.Snippet));
   }

   return vids;
}
```

I did verify that all 3 videos are public, and do play on YouTube.